# how to give different id while appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am appending data in nested list .I  am successfully append data Not I want to give id to the time.
I study from this link

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-append

HTML:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<button id="test">test</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [
      { text: "foo" }
    ]
  });
  $('#test').click(function () {  
    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    treeview.append({ text: "bar" });
    treeview.append({ text: "b" });
    treeview.append({ text: "bar" });
    // appends a new node to the root level
    //treeview.append({ text: "baz" }, $("#treeview .k-item:first"));
    treeview.append(treeview.findByText("bar"), treeview.findByText("b")); 
  });
});
```

I make demo in here http://jsbin.com/suhujewi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hmm...unable to understand the question.

Comment: I want to give id when I am adding data .If i am adding data "a" it id should be "1".in my example i am appending "bar" i want to give id "0"."1" "2"

Comment: As we are giving id to "button", Now I want to give id to all list elements and nested list element

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/3j9kL/49/

Javascript:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
   dragAndDrop: true
});
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
treeview.append({ text: "Naveen",expanded : true }, $("#treeview"));
var foundNode = treeview.findByText("Naveen");
foundNode.attr("id", "3");
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="treeview">
    <li id="1" data-expanded="true">Foo</li>
    <li id="2" data-expanded="true">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

You can modify according to your needs.